# Weird FormatException with Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a frustratingly weird Form

[image]

I've also tried changing it to `job.Tags |= Convert.ToInt32(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but even that gives the same exception.

I have absolutely no idea why.

Here is a character representation of `item`
[image]

And here is my code

```cs
if (model.TagSelection != null)
{
    foreach (var item in model.TagSelection)
    {
        job.Tags |= Convert.ToInt32(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `item` has some non-printable characters at the start or end. Try examining `item.Length`. A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you - along with showing the code and the exception as *text*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added item.Lenght and also each character. I still don't understand where that comes from. I have it as "256" in a different class

Comment: Right, the new screenshot shows exactly what's wrong - your string starts with U+202D and ends with U+202C, which are to do with left-to-right and right-to-left. I don't know what you mean by 'I have it as "256" in a different class' but this is clearly a string of length 5, not a string of length 3. So the problem isn't in Convert.ToInt32, it's in how you're getting your data.

Comment: @JohnG my data I get like this
new SelectListItem() { Value = "256", Text= "Bad Recalibration"} which is then on a HTML page in a multiselect dropdown

Comment: Yes you are correct and I was mistaken.

Comment: @DonaldJansen: Well that's not the data that's coming back... you need to diagnose how you're getting different data back. I suggest you look very carefully at the exact bytes in the request, and in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has come from copying the values from Excel, not sure why it is doing it but after deleting it and retyping it the error has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Item Length is 5 - the numeric characters are delimited by double quotes (as you'd code but not expect to see in captured data). Since you are getting the string `"256"`, you'll have to `Replace()` them with `string.Empty` to get a numerics-only string length 3, which should then convert.

```
  var s = "\"256\"";
  var s2 = s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Edit: I just realized it's worse than it appears.  I think those are left- and right-slanted quotes (note the character codes 823x).  You may need something more like this...

```
var s3 = new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```